# Existence of an infinite countable compact subset of $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Studying compactness, I wondered whether a countable (and infinite) subset of $\mathbf{R}$ could be compact and I looked for examples of such sets, but I did not find anything. Is there any theorem or counter-example related to this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\{\,\tfrac 1n\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}\cup\{0\} $$

Comment: How do you prove its compactness ?

Comment: @MrMaths : It is closed and bounded (its only limit point is $0$, and it is contained in $[0,1]$). Or it is simple to extract a finite subcover from any open cover because any neighborhood of $0$ will contain all but at most finitely many of the points.

Comment: @MrMaths Alternatively, if you don't want to use that theorem, consider an open cover of the set, and note that any open set containing $0$ has to contain all but finitely many of the other points ...

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But how do you show that it is closed @MPW ?

Comment: I agree with your argument using an open cover @MPW

Answer (score 3):

What about $\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}\cup \{0\}$?

Comment: How do you prove its compactness ?